# How can i split a textfile and store 2 values in one line?

Tags: java, text, save, storage, java-io

I have a text file -> 23/34 <- and I'm working on a Java program.

I want to store them out in `String One = 23` and `anotherString = 34` and put them together to one string to write them down in a text file, but it dosen't work. :( Everytime it makes a break. Maybe because the split method but I don't know how to separate them.

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (textfile) );
    try {
        while( (textfile= in.readLine()) != null ) {
            String[] parts = textfileString.split("/");
            String one = parts[0];
        }
    }
}
```

When I print or store `one + "/" + anotherString`, it makes a line-break at one but I want it all in one line. :(

Comment: How are you printing it? Have you tried something like, `System.out.printf("%s/%s\n", parts[0], parts[1]);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have never shown us how you are writing the file, so we can't really help you with your code. This is a bit of a more modern approach, but I think it does what you want.

```
File infile = new File("input.txt");
File outfile = new File("output.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(infile.toPath());
     BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outfile.toPath())) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split("/");
        String one = parts[0];
        String two = parts[1];
        writer.write(one + "/" + two);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: Then do so? I don't see a problem, this isn't big of a modification.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("output.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String string1 = line.split("/")[0];
        String string2 = line.split("/")[1];
        bw.write(string1 + string2 + "\n");
        bw.flush();
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}
```

On file:

```
23/34
```

Resulted in output.txt containing:

```
2334
```

You need to read in each line, and split it on your designated character ("/"). Then assign string1 to the first split, and string2 to the second split. You can then do with the variables as you want. To output them to a file, you simply append them together with a `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
    InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./test.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    String currentLine;

    try {
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = currentLine.split("/");
            System.out.println(parts[0] + "/" + parts[1]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```